# How do I display a substitute password character in a UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a need to display a `UITableView` containing a user's account credentials. For this, I'm using `UILabels` in `UITableViewCell`. When I display their password, I'd obviously like to just display a placeholder password character instead of their actual password, similar to a `UITextField` when it's set to secure text entry mode. In fact, I'd like to use the same character as `UITextField` uses, instead of '*'.

My question is, what is the character code for the password character the `UITextField` when it's in secure mode?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not just use a UITextField, make the field non-editable and change the border style to make it look like a UILabel?

Answer (score 18):

Here's a way to do this, e.g., to display the password "dotted out" in a Prototype Cell's detailTextLabel:

```
// self.password is your password string
NSMutableString *dottedPassword = [NSMutableString new];

for (int i = 0; i < [self.password length]; i++)
{
    [dottedPassword appendString:@"●"]; // BLACK CIRCLE Unicode: U+25CF, UTF-8: E2 97 8F
}

cell.detailTextLabel.text = dottedPassword;
```

Answer (score 3):

The password character is probably a bullet.  On a Mac, option-8 will insert one wherever you are typing.  The Character Palette says it is Unicode **2022** and UTF8 **E2 80 A2**.

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 10, the BLACK CIRCLE Unicode character is not consistent with the secure text field anymore. The character to use is ⦁ "Z NOTATION SPOT" (U+2981).

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 3 you can use:

```
passwordLabel.text = String(password.characters.map { _ in return "•" })
```

Answer (score 2):

Although a very old question, I came across the same problem.
benzado has the right idee, although I think the Unicode should be [25cf](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25cf/index.htm). To me it looks like that's exactly the dot apple uses in a secured UITextField.