# UITextfield password placeholder dots

Tags: ios, security, passwords, uitextfield, placeholder

Do I have to set the placeholder of a password field with dots or can I make the setSecureTextEntry:YES apply to the placeholder text, rather than just entered text?

I'm trying to implement a settings screen with username and password among other fields similar to the account settings for Mail or iCloud accounts.

Setting the password UITextfield secure works fine in replacing characters with dots as I'm typing, but when I navigate away from the settings page then navigate back to it, the placeholder value for the password is displayed in plain text.

Is this the only way to get dots to show up as placeholder text for passwords:

```
NSString *name  =  [settingNames  objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
NSString *value =  [settingValues objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

if ([name isEqualToString:@"Password"]) 
{
    [settingTextField setPlaceholder:@"••••••••••"];
    [settingTextField setSecureTextEntry:YES];
}
else 
{
    [settingTextField setPlaceholder:value];
}
```

If I use the value rather than the string of dots, the value is being displayed as plain text.

This is where I got the idea to use a string of dots: [How do I display a substitute password character in a UILabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83687/how-do-i-display-a-substitute-password-character-in-a-uilabel)

This code is being displayed in a tableview.  The values are being stored and retrieved as NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in viewWillAppear so when you navigate back this code will be executed again.

Comment: This code is in - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath so it's not practical to put it in viewWillAppear.  There are a number of fields that are being put in the table, and if it is a password field, I want to obscure the password value.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *dots =@"";

    for (int i=0; i<Password.length; i++) {
        dots=[dots stringByAppendingString:@"•"];


    }

    settingTextField.placeholder=dots;
```

Comment: A bit of explanation would be nice!

Comment: This answer misses the point.  If I use [settingTextField setSecureTextEntry:YES]; then everything I type shows as dots.  But if I set the placeholder for the password as [settingTextField setPlaceholder:value]; it shows the password, even if I have the setSecureTextEntry:YES set.  So instead of using the value, I'm filling it with dots.  Is there a way to do it without filling in dots?

Comment: I think there is no way to do that, because place holders are not meant to be show the original data, usually it is used to gave a hint about the text field's usage.