# Get the width of UITextField secured text

Tags: ios, swift

I have an UITextField, and when I set `isSecureTextEntry` as true, it replaces the text with dots, but this code:

`let size = (text as NSString?)?.size(withAttributes: typingAttributes)`

gets the unsecured text width. How to get secured text width (with dots)?

Added two screenshots below. Checkmark should be near the text.

[secured field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2yk8.png)

[unsecured field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQPFx.png)

Comment: I do not believe this is possible (and I believe it is somewhat intentionally not possible, so even if you figure out a way I would not be surprised to see it break in future releases). I would recommend redesigning your UI to put the checkmark outside the field.

Comment: Not sure about robustness of this code but atleast you can try `"•".size(withAttributes: typingAttributes) * text.count + someMargin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a string with the same number of bullets character(•) as the text then get the length of it. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83687/how-do-i-display-a-substitute-password-character-in-a-uilabel/9304081) suggests some possible characters used by iOS as the bullets, including [U+2022](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm), [U+2981](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2981/index.htm) and [U+25cf](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25cf/index.htm). You may try them out.

Comment: Secure entry fields do not promise to show the same number of dots as there are characters in the field. If you paste into the field, it generally puts a large number of dots, even for a short piece of text.